# Navigation bar keeps hiding content under it

Tags: html, css, layout, navbar

I'm new to web development and in this example I'm working on: http://codepen.io/wabibito/pen/RawGPo

```
<head>
  <title>Tiago Dias Ferreira</title>
  <style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: static;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>    
    </ul>
  </nav>

    <a  name="home"></a>
    <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Tiago Dias Ferreira</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum rhoncus aliquam velit eget luctus. Proin suscipit lorem ex, ut porta nulla dignissim eu. Praesent at tristique risus, sit amet lacinia urna. Quisque vitae congue mauris, et facilisis nulla. Sed quam dolor, blandit ac velit in, luctus vehicula felis. Donec fringilla urna dolor, ac semper quam congue non. Praesent vel nunc eleifend, mattis ipsum eget, vestibulum eros. Nunc et semper massa.
    </p>
    <p>
      In tortor dui, cursus a velit ac, convallis hendrerit ligula. Nunc ultricies efficitur nisl. Suspendisse condimentum porttitor maximus. Morbi purus nunc, posuere id gravida ac, suscipit at urna. Phasellus non diam vitae mauris aliquet porttitor tincidunt id nibh. Nullam imperdiet nisl eu est imperdiet, porttitor vehicula metus iaculis. Donec rutrum eget tortor a consequat. Maecenas ac arcu erat. Fusce rhoncus nisl eget elementum pharetra. Proin a enim ac mauris mattis ultricies quis a dolor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nullam ornare non nibh sed cursus. Phasellus volutpat nisi eu nunc dignissim semper. Vivamus nec neque mi. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vehicula augue tristique bibendum faucibus. Nam in imperdiet orci, in molestie ante. Pellentesque maximus ex a risus gravida, eget rhoncus neque venenatis.
    </p>
    <p>
      In nec imperdiet diam, at malesuada justo. Donec venenatis in nulla sed consequat. Nunc hendrerit, turpis ut viverra dapibus, tortor lorem consequat sem, ut dapibus massa nisl sit amet arcu. Proin tempor tincidunt ipsum et molestie. Pellentesque vulputate velit sit amet tellus iaculis, eget viverra nibh malesuada. Proin tristique nunc vitae magna cursus, at blandit dolor faucibus. Aenean dignissim sit amet arcu eget vestibulum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vivamus nec diam non urna pellentesque varius at non tellus. Pellentesque interdum faucibus maximus. Phasellus diam sapien, tincidunt quis cursus at, accumsan eget diam. Integer ullamcorper nulla nec justo consectetur, porta faucibus mauris gravida. Maecenas sagittis sodales velit, et tempor libero efficitur et. Suspendisse pulvinar at nisi quis interdum. In in vestibulum turpis, eget suscipit massa. Nullam faucibus sodales ornare. Mauris at ultricies ex, sit amet convallis lorem.
    </p>
        <a  name="about"></a>
    <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Tiago Dias Ferreira</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum rhoncus aliquam velit eget luctus. Proin suscipit lorem ex, ut porta nulla dignissim eu. Praesent at tristique risus, sit amet lacinia urna. Quisque vitae congue mauris, et facilisis nulla. Sed quam dolor, blandit ac velit in, luctus vehicula felis. Donec fringilla urna dolor, ac semper quam congue non. Praesent vel nunc eleifend, mattis ipsum eget, vestibulum eros. Nunc et semper massa.
    </p>
    <p>
      In tortor dui, cursus a velit ac, convallis hendrerit ligula. Nunc ultricies efficitur nisl. Suspendisse condimentum porttitor maximus. Morbi purus nunc, posuere id gravida ac, suscipit at urna. Phasellus non diam vitae mauris aliquet porttitor tincidunt id nibh. Nullam imperdiet nisl eu est imperdiet, porttitor vehicula metus iaculis. Donec rutrum eget tortor a consequat. Maecenas ac arcu erat. Fusce rhoncus nisl eget elementum pharetra. Proin a enim ac mauris mattis ultricies quis a dolor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nullam ornare non nibh sed cursus. Phasellus volutpat nisi eu nunc dignissim semper. Vivamus nec neque mi. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vehicula augue tristique bibendum faucibus. Nam in imperdiet orci, in molestie ante. Pellentesque maximus ex a risus gravida, eget rhoncus neque venenatis.
    </p>
    <p>
      In nec imperdiet diam, at malesuada justo. Donec venenatis in nulla sed consequat. Nunc hendrerit, turpis ut viverra dapibus, tortor lorem consequat sem, ut dapibus massa nisl sit amet arcu. Proin tempor tincidunt ipsum et molestie. Pellentesque vulputate velit sit amet tellus iaculis, eget viverra nibh malesuada. Proin tristique nunc vitae magna cursus, at blandit dolor faucibus. Aenean dignissim sit amet arcu eget vestibulum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vivamus nec diam non urna pellentesque varius at non tellus. Pellentesque interdum faucibus maximus. Phasellus diam sapien, tincidunt quis cursus at, accumsan eget diam. Integer ullamcorper nulla nec justo consectetur, porta faucibus mauris gravida. Maecenas sagittis sodales velit, et tempor libero efficitur et. Suspendisse pulvinar at nisi quis interdum. In in vestibulum turpis, eget suscipit massa. Nullam faucibus sodales ornare. Mauris at ultricies ex, sit amet convallis lorem.
    </p>
        <a  name="portfolio"></a>
    <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Tiago Dias Ferreira</h1>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum rhoncus aliquam velit eget luctus. Proin suscipit lorem ex, ut porta nulla dignissim eu. Praesent at tristique risus, sit amet lacinia urna. Quisque vitae congue mauris, et facilisis nulla. Sed quam dolor, blandit ac velit in, luctus vehicula felis. Donec fringilla urna dolor, ac semper quam congue non. Praesent vel nunc eleifend, mattis ipsum eget, vestibulum eros. Nunc et semper massa.
    </p>
    <p>
      In tortor dui, cursus a velit ac, convallis hendrerit ligula. Nunc ultricies efficitur nisl. Suspendisse condimentum porttitor maximus. Morbi purus nunc, posuere id gravida ac, suscipit at urna. Phasellus non diam vitae mauris aliquet porttitor tincidunt id nibh. Nullam imperdiet nisl eu est imperdiet, porttitor vehicula metus iaculis. Donec rutrum eget tortor a consequat. Maecenas ac arcu erat. Fusce rhoncus nisl eget elementum pharetra. Proin a enim ac mauris mattis ultricies quis a dolor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nullam ornare non nibh sed cursus. Phasellus volutpat nisi eu nunc dignissim semper. Vivamus nec neque mi. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vehicula augue tristique bibendum faucibus. Nam in imperdiet orci, in molestie ante. Pellentesque maximus ex a risus gravida, eget rhoncus neque venenatis.
    </p>
    <p>
      In nec imperdiet diam, at malesuada justo. Donec venenatis in nulla sed consequat. Nunc hendrerit, turpis ut viverra dapibus, tortor lorem consequat sem, ut dapibus massa nisl sit amet arcu. Proin tempor tincidunt ipsum et molestie. Pellentesque vulputate velit sit amet tellus iaculis, eget viverra nibh malesuada. Proin tristique nunc vitae magna cursus, at blandit dolor faucibus. Aenean dignissim sit amet arcu eget vestibulum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vivamus nec diam non urna pellentesque varius at non tellus. Pellentesque interdum faucibus maximus. Phasellus diam sapien, tincidunt quis cursus at, accumsan eget diam. Integer ullamcorper nulla nec justo consectetur, porta faucibus mauris gravida. Maecenas sagittis sodales velit, et tempor libero efficitur et. Suspendisse pulvinar at nisi quis interdum. In in vestibulum turpis, eget suscipit massa. Nullam faucibus sodales ornare. Mauris at ultricies ex, sit amet convallis lorem.
    </p>
        <a  name="contact"></a>
    <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Tiago Dias Ferreira</h1>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum rhoncus aliquam velit eget luctus. Proin suscipit lorem ex, ut porta nulla dignissim eu. Praesent at tristique risus, sit amet lacinia urna. Quisque vitae congue mauris, et facilisis nulla. Sed quam dolor, blandit ac velit in, luctus vehicula felis. Donec fringilla urna dolor, ac semper quam congue non. Praesent vel nunc eleifend, mattis ipsum eget, vestibulum eros. Nunc et semper massa.
    </p>
    <p>
      In tortor dui, cursus a velit ac, convallis hendrerit ligula. Nunc ultricies efficitur nisl. Suspendisse condimentum porttitor maximus. Morbi purus nunc, posuere id gravida ac, suscipit at urna. Phasellus non diam vitae mauris aliquet porttitor tincidunt id nibh. Nullam imperdiet nisl eu est imperdiet, porttitor vehicula metus iaculis. Donec rutrum eget tortor a consequat. Maecenas ac arcu erat. Fusce rhoncus nisl eget elementum pharetra. Proin a enim ac mauris mattis ultricies quis a dolor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nullam ornare non nibh sed cursus. Phasellus volutpat nisi eu nunc dignissim semper. Vivamus nec neque mi. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vehicula augue tristique bibendum faucibus. Nam in imperdiet orci, in molestie ante. Pellentesque maximus ex a risus gravida, eget rhoncus neque venenatis.
    </p>
    <p>
      In nec imperdiet diam, at malesuada justo. Donec venenatis in nulla sed consequat. Nunc hendrerit, turpis ut viverra dapibus, tortor lorem consequat sem, ut dapibus massa nisl sit amet arcu. Proin tempor tincidunt ipsum et molestie. Pellentesque vulputate velit sit amet tellus iaculis, eget viverra nibh malesuada. Proin tristique nunc vitae magna cursus, at blandit dolor faucibus. Aenean dignissim sit amet arcu eget vestibulum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vivamus nec diam non urna pellentesque varius at non tellus. Pellentesque interdum faucibus maximus. Phasellus diam sapien, tincidunt quis cursus at, accumsan eget diam. Integer ullamcorper nulla nec justo consectetur, porta faucibus mauris gravida. Maecenas sagittis sodales velit, et tempor libero efficitur et. Suspendisse pulvinar at nisi quis interdum. In in vestibulum turpis, eget suscipit massa. Nullam faucibus sodales ornare. Mauris at ultricies ex, sit amet convallis lorem.
    </p>
</body>
```

The navigation bar keeps hiding content under it. Initially i fixed it by putting a margin to the first title. But when I click on links on the same page, they get hidden under the navigation bar.

How can I fix it?
I also accept others suggestions, tips and hints to improve. :D

Cheers,
Tiago

Comment: Seems like it might be a codepen thing because it works as expected in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkcy1c7c/

Answer (score 2):

The fixed nav bar is the problem. When you set something as fixed, it removes it from the DOM and subsequently all other content will be rendered as if it's not there. Meaning it will display content at the top of the page and then put hte navbar on top. You need to add padding to the body to bring it down. For example, if the nav bar height is 50px, add body {padding-top:50px} to your css.

Also - just looking at your code, if you are using the nav to target sections on the page via the href, you will need to add that as an id to the a link in the page - currently you have only listed a name for each link in the body. And they should be semantically listed as "section" as well (enclosing the heading and `<p>` elements of that section)- currently you have numerous h1 elements, but you should only have one per page with other headings being h2, h3 etc (it is fine to have a h1 for each section if using the section nomenclature because it infers that each section is semantically different from the others and therefore can have a new h1). hope this helps gavgrif

Comment: Thanks, @gavgrif You helped a lot! I figured it out including a padding to each section I made.